# "Requires editing" button in first post review?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues

While doing first post reviews, I felt on a question that would have been good, but clearly requires editing (but there is no "Requires editing" button in first posts review).

I don't consider myself like being the best "Editor" though. Even if I would be, what if I don't feel like editing at all?

So remaining choices here are :

1. Down vote (not apropriate, as the good question just requires editing)
2. No action needed (which is not true ! )
3. Up vote and hope someone cares about editing.
4. Skip... which is like not doing anything and thus, not helping at all.

I searched a bit on SO with the keywords in the title and could not find anything related.

Is there an appropriate behavior in this situation? New feature to come?

Comment: If you don't feel like editing at all, you probably shouldn't review these queue? It's the whole point of this queue to get questions into shape before they stay on the site too long.

Comment: So... Stop reviewing in first posts if you can't edit them. Alright, i guess i will just stick to some triage. Or... nothing.

Comment: The point of the review queues is to *solve the problem*, not to kick the can further down the road. If you cannot or are unwilling to solve the problem, either "Skip" until you find one you can fix, or don't review at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're doing a first post review and a post requires editing then *edit the post*.  That's what that queue is there for (among other things).

In Triage the whole design of the queue is that it doesn't actually handle anything, it just directs posts to another queue where they get actually handled.  First posts isn't like that.  You're supposed to actually do everything you can to aid that post when you're reviewing a first post, and if it needs editing that means editing it.

Answer (score 6):

As said by [Omar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar):

### [There's no shame in using skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/5764553)

Keep skipping until you find something you can do. Some first posts don't need editing. Either they are perfect already or they're too bad to keep (and should just be flagged). And there may also be posts that you feel are within your editing ability.

**It's perfectly fine to keep clicking skip until you reach one that you feel able to review.** Even though it may feel like you're not helping, you are. If you skip 99% of the posts you see, there's still 1% that you are contributing, and that's more than nothing. (Whether you consider it to be worth your time may be another matter...)

Comment: There is also the option to filter by (up to 3) tags. If you only feel comfortable in one or two technologies, then you can just look at those types of posts.